# Integration with $\geq 1$ variable

Tags: calculus, integration

[image: Integration region]

I do not know how I would integrate the region in the image above; how would I choose the appropriate bounds (particularly for $y$?) Would I integrate y from $y = x$ to $0$? Or from $0$ to $y = x$?

Comment: Either start with $x\in[0,1]$, then $y\in[0,1-x]$, or the converse, $y\in[0,1]$ then $x\in[0,1-y]$.

Comment: For intuition, try drawing lots of thin rectangles lined up that attempt to approximate the region.

Comment: To make things more concrete, the region is the set $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: 0\leq y\leq 1-x\leq 1\}$ (alternatively with strict inequalities).

Comment: Integrating $f$ over this region gives $\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}f(x,\,y)dydx$, which can also be written in some other ways. Do you want to take $f=y$? (That's what I inferred from your question, but @RodiRaketa's answer uses $f=1$.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a double integral, then you have two options:

$\int_0^1 \int_0^{-x+1} dy\,dx$

or

$\int_0^1 \int_0^{-y+1} dx\,dy$